# Combined number of events when event with one rate triggers a new event with a different rate

Tags: calculus

let's say I have an event A happening at a rate X per second. Every event A will trigger  event B that will be repeated at a rate Y per second. How can I calculate the total number of A and B events in a period of time Z seconds?